# Synònŷmïzé [accented-strings] a͘n̲̻̹͍d̵̤͍̩ ̸̬[non-ascii-chars] a̰͖̫̺͟s͓͔̬̺͖͉̣̕ ̞̘w̯͉e̠͈̟͜l̻̻̗̀l̵

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

It seems to me that [accented-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accented-strings) is just a naive duplicate of [non-ascii-chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/non-ascii-chars); both tags seem to deal with encoding issues - typically, someone who happens to insert an accented letter (or anything beyond ASCII) in his application and everything breaks down.

One of them is surely redundant and should be synonymized with the other, although one could argue that questions tagged as any of them should just have the more generic [character-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/character-encoding).

Comment: Renaming suggestion: `Bürninátë [accented-strings]`

Comment: @Pekka웃: seems like a good occasion to throw in some zalgo as well

Comment: I can see there is a master at work here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think [non-ascii-chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/non-ascii-chars) is the better choice here (since it's kinda/sorta more general), but I really dislike the short "chars" in there.

I propose renaming/merging [non-ascii-chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/non-ascii-chars) into [non-ascii-characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/non-ascii-characters), and then synonymizing/merging [accented-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accented-strings) into that.

Comment: You meant `[äccèntëd-stríngs]` and `non-a̰͖̫̺͟s͓͔̬̺͖͉̣̕cii-characters`

Comment: @Pekka웃: An easy mistake to make, surely.

Comment: A common typo. The keys are like right next to each other.

Comment: Ok this seems to me a reasonable solution, and it seems we have some consensus here. Now how does it work? Do I have to mark as accepted and someone clicks a magic button for the synonym+rename? (I can't for sure, since I don't have enough upvotes in [tag:accented-strings] or [tag:non-ascii-chars], and I don't know who could have them).

Comment: (sorry, I'm not very experienced in meta.so and how tag renaming works)

Comment: @MatteoItalia Normally, a moderator would take care of things. But since I'm here anyway... this is done.